# how to create a new column in a dataframe from values in another?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, indexing

I have df1:

```
index  Year  var1  var2  var3
0      2010  8     9     10
1      2011  11    12    13
.
.
998    2012  4     1     55
999    2011  19    10    18
```

and I have df2

```
index  var4
2010   7.5
2011   5.7
2012   4.9
```

How can I create a new column in `df1` called `var4` that matches the column `Year` with `index` of df2 and return `var4`. I have different rows for two tables and in my data years are between 2008 to 2018.

Comment: oh I am totally uneducated about merges. I think it is helpful. I am going to read the answers. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer actually but it looks lame. Please let me know if you have a better option.

```
df1['var4'] = np.where(df['Year'] == 2010, df2[2010],
              np.where(df['Year'] == 2011, df2[2011],
              np.where(df['Year'] == 2012, df2[2012], 'NaN')))
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, use `merge`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Year": np.random.randint(2010, 2013, size=10),
                    "var1": np.random.randint(20, 40, size=10),
                    "var2": np.random.randint(30, 50, size=10),
                    "var3": np.random.randint(10, 60, size=10)}).rename_axis("index")

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"var4": [7.5, 5.7, 4.9]},
                   index=[2010, 2011, 2012]).rename_axis("index")
```

```
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on="Year", right_index=True, how="left")
       Year  var1  var2  var3  var4
index
0      2010    39    30    19   7.5
1      2012    39    34    51   4.9
2      2010    38    44    12   7.5
3      2011    37    31    39   5.7
4      2012    29    41    42   4.9
5      2010    29    49    57   7.5
6      2011    22    48    13   5.7
7      2011    36    31    53   5.7
8      2011    31    31    56   5.7
9      2010    25    41    43   7.5
```